# Auto hide response message

Tags: javascript, html

Am JavaScript newbie, and i wanted some help.

the above script can validate valid and invalidate credit card / debit

my problem is that, how can i clear the "invalid credit / debit card number" error message when user has started typing again the card

its like i want to auto clear error message when user has re-type again

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <style>
            
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Payment
      <img style="visibility: hidden" class="mastercard" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/mastercard.png">
      <img style="visibility: hidden" class="visacard" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/visa.png">
      <img style="visibility: hidden" class="discovercard" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/discover.png">
      <img style="visibility: hidden" class="amexcard" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/amex.png">
    </h2>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name-on-card">Name on Card</label>
      <input class="cc_name" type="text" name="card-name" class="form-control" placeholder="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="cc-number">Credit card number</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cc_number" name="cc_number" placeholder="" maxlength="20">
      <span id="loginError"></span>
    </div>
    <!--<div class="">
      <select class="month_year_select" name="month" id="month">
        <option value="">exp month</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <select class="month_year_select" id="year" name="year">
        <option value="">exp year</option>
      </select>
    </div>-->
    <div class="CVV">
      <label for="cc-cvv">CVV</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cc-cvv" name="cc-cvv" placeholder="" maxlength="4">
    </div>
       <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('cc-cvv').addEventListener('change', CWcheck); //recommended way
document.getElementById('cc_number').onchange = creditCheck; //it is OK too

function CWcheck() { //function name should conventionally start with lower case but isn't big deal
  //"this" is the element which fired the event
  if (!/^\d{3,4}$/.test(this.value)) {
    this.value = '';
    this.focus();
    alert('CVV is 3 or 4 digits');
  }
}

function creditCheck() {
  // hide cc logos
  var ccImgs = document.querySelectorAll('h2 img');
  for (var i = 0, ccImg; ccImg = ccImgs[i]; ++i) {
    ccImg.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
  var ccNum = this.value.replace(/\D/g, ''); //remove all non-digits
  if (ccNum.length < 15 /*15 is amex*/ || ccNum.length > 16) {
    document.getElementById("loginError").innerHTML = "invalid credit / debit card number";
    this.focus();
    return false;
  }
  //implement Luhn algorithm
  var check = ccNum.split('') //get array
    .reverse()
    .map(function(el, index) {
      return el * (index % 2 + 1); //multiply even positions by 2
    })
    .join('') //combine array of strings
    .split('')
    .reduce(function(a, b) { //sum digits
      return a + (b - 0);
    }, 0);
  if (!check || (check % 10)) { //checksum should be none-zero and dividable by 10
    document.getElementById("loginError").innerHTML = "invalid credit / debit card number";
    this.focus();
    return false;
  }
  //test passed. show card logo
  if (/^5[1-5]/.test(ccNum))
    document.querySelector('h2 img.mastercard').style.visibility = 'visible';
  else if (/^4/.test(ccNum))
    document.querySelector('h2 img.visacard').style.visibility = 'visible';
  else if (ccNum.length == 15 && /^3[47]/.test(ccNum))
    document.querySelector('h2 img.amexcard').style.visibility = 'visible';
  else if (/^6011/.test(ccNum))
    document.querySelector('h2 img.discovercasd').style.visibility = 'visible';
  //and so on
  else {
    document.getElementById("loginError").innerHTML = "invalid credit / debit card number";
    this.focus();
    return false;
  }

  //test passed. format the string
  this.value = ccNum
    .replace(/^(\d{4})(\d{4})(\d{4})(\d+)$/, '$1 $2 $3 $4');
}
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Have you tried using 'keyup' or 'keydown' events on the text fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a `input` event listener to the input, and based on the length of text present in input, I clear the error message (if its length is greater than 0, which marks user has started typing again.)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Payment
    <img style="visibility: hidden" class="mastercard" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/mastercard.png">
    <img style="visibility: hidden" class="visacard" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/visa.png">
    <img style="visibility: hidden" class="discovercard" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/discover.png">
    <img style="visibility: hidden" class="amexcard" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/amex.png">
  </h2>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name-on-card">Name on Card</label>
    <input class="cc_name" type="text" name="card-name" class="form-control" placeholder="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="cc-number">Credit card number</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cc_number" name="cc_number" placeholder="" maxlength="20">
    <span id="loginError"></span>
  </div>
  <!--<div class="">
      <select class="month_year_select" name="month" id="month">
        <option value="">exp month</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <select class="month_year_select" id="year" name="year">
        <option value="">exp year</option>
      </select>
    </div>-->
  <div class="CVV">
    <label for="cc-cvv">CVV</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cc-cvv" name="cc-cvv" placeholder="" maxlength="4">
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('cc-cvv').addEventListener('change', CWcheck); //recommended way
    document.getElementById('cc_number').onchange = creditCheck; //it is OK too

    function CWcheck() { //function name should conventionally start with lower case but isn't big deal
      //"this" is the element which fired the event
      if (!/^\d{3,4}$/.test(this.value)) {
        this.value = '';
        this.focus();
        alert('CVV is 3 or 4 digits');
      }
    }

    function creditCheck() {
      // hide cc logos
      var ccImgs = document.querySelectorAll('h2 img');
      for (var i = 0, ccImg; ccImg = ccImgs[i]; ++i) {
        ccImg.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      }
      var ccNum = this.value.replace(/\D/g, ''); //remove all non-digits
      if (ccNum.length < 15 /*15 is amex*/ || ccNum.length > 16) {
        document.getElementById("loginError").innerHTML = "invalid credit / debit card number";
        this.focus();
        return false;
      }
      //implement Luhn algorithm
      var check = ccNum.split('') //get array
        .reverse()
        .map(function(el, index) {
          return el * (index % 2 + 1); //multiply even positions by 2
        })
        .join('') //combine array of strings
        .split('')
        .reduce(function(a, b) { //sum digits
          return a + (b - 0);
        }, 0);
      if (!check || (check % 10)) { //checksum should be none-zero and dividable by 10
        document.getElementById("loginError").innerHTML = "invalid credit / debit card number";
        this.focus();
        return false;
      }
      //test passed. show card logo
      if (/^5[1-5]/.test(ccNum))
        document.querySelector('h2 img.mastercard').style.visibility = 'visible';
      else if (/^4/.test(ccNum))
        document.querySelector('h2 img.visacard').style.visibility = 'visible';
      else if (ccNum.length == 15 && /^3[47]/.test(ccNum))
        document.querySelector('h2 img.amexcard').style.visibility = 'visible';
      else if (/^6011/.test(ccNum))
        document.querySelector('h2 img.discovercasd').style.visibility = 'visible';
      //and so on
      else {
        document.getElementById("loginError").innerHTML = "invalid credit / debit card number";
        this.focus();
        return false;
      }

      //test passed. format the string
      this.value = ccNum
        .replace(/^(\d{4})(\d{4})(\d{4})(\d+)$/, '$1 $2 $3 $4');
    }

    document.querySelector("#cc_number").addEventListener("input", function() {
      if (document.querySelector("#cc_number").value.length > 0) {
        document.getElementById("loginError").innerHTML = "";
      }
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I'd suggest adding a line to clear the error message into your event handler:

```
document.getElementById('cc-cvv').addEventListener('change', function() {
    document.getElementById("loginError").innerHTML = "";
    CWcheck();
});
```

This will reset the message to an empty string every time a keystroke is read. It'll also show error messages when the check comes back as invalid.

Hopes this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this. With your current setup you could use a class to show and hide the error rather than adding the innerHTML. This class could just be removed after each change. Example with your code, attached.

```js
document.getElementById('cc-cvv').addEventListener('change', CWcheck); //recommended way
document.getElementById('cc_number').onchange = creditCheck; //it is OK too

function CWcheck() { //function name should conventionally start with lower case but isn't big deal
  //"this" is the element which fired the event
  if (!/^\d{3,4}$/.test(this.value)) {
    this.value = '';
    this.focus();
    alert('CVV is 3 or 4 digits');
  }
}

function creditCheck() {
   document.getElementById("loginError").classList.remove('card-error--active')
  
  // hide cc logos
  var ccImgs = document.querySelectorAll('h2 img');
  for (var i = 0, ccImg; ccImg = ccImgs[i]; ++i) {
    ccImg.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
  var ccNum = this.value.replace(/\D/g, ''); //remove all non-digits
  if (ccNum.length < 15 /*15 is amex*/ || ccNum.length > 16) {
     document.getElementById("loginError").classList.add('card-error--active')
    this.focus();
    return false;
  }
  //implement Luhn algorithm
  var check = ccNum.split('') //get array
    .reverse()
    .map(function(el, index) {
      return el * (index % 2 + 1); //multiply even positions by 2
    })
    .join('') //combine array of strings
    .split('')
    .reduce(function(a, b) { //sum digits
      return a + (b - 0);
    }, 0);
  if (!check || (check % 10)) { //checksum should be none-zero and dividable by 10
    document.getElementById("loginError").classList.add('card-error--active')
    this.focus();
    return false;
  }
  //test passed. show card logo
  if (/^5[1-5]/.test(ccNum))
    document.querySelector('h2 img.mastercard').style.visibility = 'visible';
  else if (/^4/.test(ccNum))
    document.querySelector('h2 img.visacard').style.visibility = 'visible';
  else if (ccNum.length == 15 && /^3[47]/.test(ccNum))
    document.querySelector('h2 img.amexcard').style.visibility = 'visible';
  else if (/^6011/.test(ccNum))
    document.querySelector('h2 img.discovercasd').style.visibility = 'visible';
  //and so on
  else {
    document.getElementById("loginError").innerHTML = "invalid credit / debit card number";
    this.focus();
    return false;
  }

  //test passed. format the string
  this.value = ccNum
    .replace(/^(\d{4})(\d{4})(\d{4})(\d+)$/, '$1 $2 $3 $4');
}
```

```css
.card-error{
  display:none;
}

.card-error--active{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <style>
            
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Payment
      <img style="visibility: hidden" class="mastercard" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/mastercard.png">
      <img style="visibility: hidden" class="visacard" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/visa.png">
      <img style="visibility: hidden" class="discovercard" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/discover.png">
      <img style="visibility: hidden" class="amexcard" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/amex.png">
    </h2>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name-on-card">Name on Card</label>
      <input class="cc_name" type="text" name="card-name" class="form-control" placeholder="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="cc-number">Credit card number</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cc_number" name="cc_number" placeholder="" maxlength="20">
      <span id="loginError" class="card-error">invalid credit / debit card number</span>
    </div>
    <!--<div class="">
      <select class="month_year_select" name="month" id="month">
        <option value="">exp month</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <select class="month_year_select" id="year" name="year">
        <option value="">exp year</option>
      </select>
    </div>-->
    <div class="CVV">
      <label for="cc-cvv">CVV</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cc-cvv" name="cc-cvv" placeholder="" maxlength="4">
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```